# Binary Search in Array of Strings

Tags: c++, arrays, search

So,I've Been Trying to Implement Binary Search in an Array of Strings for the following question
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sparse-arrays/problem?isFullScreen=true
as i'm sorting the 'strings' vector and using Binary Search to Reduce The Time Complexity but i'm coming across an error when using the stl function strcmp.

Any help in resolving the issue is Appreciated.

```
bool binarysearch(string s,vector<string > strings){
    int left = 0;
    int right = strings.size()-1;
    while(left <= right){
        int mid = (left+right)/2;
        int x = strcmp(s,strings[mid]);
        if(x == 0){
            return true;
        }else if(x < 0){
            left = mid+1;
        }else if(x > 0){
            right = mid-1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What error? Please be more specific. Anyway, with `mid` outside the loop this code is broken.

Comment: You are leaving us with very little to go on. A description of what you want your code to do vs. what it actually does would be nice and helpful. However, that said, there does seem to be an issue with your loop. It goes: Calculate `x`, check `x`, update `left` or `right` and repeat. But the calculated value of `x` does not depend on the values of `left` or `right`, so `x` may as well only be calculated once. I don't think this is the behavior you want.

Comment: `std::string`s can be compared with `==`, `strcmp` is for something else

Comment: @Evg Corrected and the issue is that i'm getting an error while trying to compile and run the programme which is "error : cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'| "
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|

Comment: That's expected. `strcmp` does not take `std::string` parameters.

Comment: @NotKev Do not use `strcmp` or use it with the `std::string` method `c_str()`

Comment: @Evg and manuell Sorry to bother you lot but is there any other method/alternative you can suggest (aside from the one manuell suggested)?

Comment: Method to do what?

Comment: Implement Binary Search in an array/vector of strings

Comment: there is `std::binary_search` which does exactly that